# Setting opacity on shape colours

Tags: java, android, xml

On android is there anyway of setting opacity on shape colours other than embedding it in the colour itself like #AARRGGBB I want to specify a colour like #RRGGBB but set the opacity using xml,

Answer (score 0):

try. alpha (0.0-1.0)

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```